# Terraform loop through 2 tuples

Tags: loops, terraform

In the below terraform code I am trying to create groups with single block. Now I am using 0,1 2 separate blocks to create. Is there any other method to create group with single block. I tried with flatten but of no luck

```
    locals {
      instances = [
        {
          instance  = "test1"
          baseUrl   = "url"
          subDomain = "sd"
          groups = [
            "app1",
            "app2",
        "app3",
      ]
},
    {
      instance  = "test2"
      baseUrl   = "url2"
      subDomain = "sd2"
      groups = [
        "t1",
        "t2",
        "t3",
      ]
},
  ]
}
resource "okta_group" "press" {
  for_each = { for k, instance in local.instances[0].groups : k => instance ]
  name     = each.value
}
resource "okta_group" "press1" {
  for_each = { for k, instance in local.instances[1].groups : k => instance ]
  name     = each.value
}
```

Comment: You would first need to define which variable are you going to use for `for_each`. So, something along the lines `for_each = local.instances`. Then you have keys and values at your disposal. So, the name would then be `name = each.value.instance` I think.

Comment: For each I tried with for_each=local.instances.instance it throws error tuple with 2 elements. I tried many different combinations and also name can be each.value I am missing proper right logic for for each loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple terms: You need to provide a single (flat) list to `for_each`. It doesn't accept list of lists or any other data structure.

Try:

```
for_each = { for k, instance in flatten(local.instances[*].groups) : k => instance}
```

which uses:

- [`flatten` - an operation to convert list of lists to a list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html)
- [and `[*]` - what they call a splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html)

I suggest reading up on these.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as if I were using flatten:

```
for_each = { for k, instance in local.instances[*].groups : k => instance }
```